# SqlDelight performance compared to Room

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I will just repost my question which I have posted on [SqlDelight Git Hub](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/discussions/4808), but I am not getting any answers. Maybe I get some info here.

Hello there. I have a question related to the performance of SqlDelight on Android.
My use case is that I have to download a large amount of data and store it.
I am inserting about 15 000 rows into a table, all 9 columns are defined as `INTEGER`.
I am using `2.0.0` of SqlDelight and for comparison, i am using room, version `2.6.0`
Here is the snippet for insertion

```kotlin
Timber.e("XXXX : MAPPED")

RoomDatabase.roomDao().insertAll(*myData)
Timber.e("XXXX : ROOMED")

SqlDelightDatabase.transaction {
    myData.forEach {
        daoSqlDelight.insert(it)
    }
}

Timber.e("XXXX : DELIGHTED")
```

Here is the output. Also, I am adding 15k rows around 5 times, and the times are more-less the same for every batch insert.

```
11:25:49.891  E  XXXX : MAPPED
11:25:50.530  E  XXXX : ROOMED // room insertion takes around 650ms
11:25:54.829  E  XXXX : DELIGHTED // sqldelight insertion takes around 4300ms
```

Here is how I create the SqlDelight DB:

```kotlin
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("SqlDelightDatabase") {
            packageName.set("com.my.package")
        }
    }
}

 AndroidSqliteDriver(
            schema = SqlDelightDatabase.Schema,
            context = get(),
            name = "somename.db",
            callback = object : AndroidSqliteDriver.Callback(CocktailsStore.Schema) {
                override fun onConfigure(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onConfigure(db)
                    setPragma(db, "JOURNAL_MODE = WAL")
                    setPragma(db, "SYNCHRONOUS = NORMAL")
                }

                private fun setPragma(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase, pragma: String) {
                    val cursor = db.query("PRAGMA $pragma")
                    cursor.moveToFirst()
                    cursor.close()
                }
            }
        )
```

I was trying firstly, without the `callback = object` part, but there is no real performance impart if I specify the callback part.

Here is the Sql.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    pram1 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    pram2 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    pram3 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    pram4 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
   // 5 more same int prams
);

insertItem:
INSERT INTO my_table (
    id,
    pram1,
    pram2,
    pram3,
    pram4,
   // more prams
) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,   ?,?,?,?,?,   ?,?,?);
```

Can you help me to improve the performance? I would like to stick to SqlDelight as I plan to port my project into KMM in the coming months.
Thanks

Comment: Isn't the Code Review Stack about improving performance?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know if I am missing something in my code or if the sqldelight is just 5x slower in this use case.

Comment: If you have questions to maintainers, It's easier to get an answer in [Kotlin Slack](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/), **#squarelibraries** channel

Comment: I will ask on Slack later, but i believe getting a proper answer on their GitHub will be beneficial for people who might have similar questions/issues in the future.

Comment: Well, I don't do much with sqldelight on Android but I do (largely) maintain the native driver. I'd suggest posting a project that somebody can clone and run directly. You'll be much more likely to get an answer, or at least get somebody to run it and make suggestions. On the numbers. I've done a fair bit of sqlite performance testing. There's not a lot of "magic" going on in the drivers. In a sample project, I'd start with stepping through the code with a debugger to see what's being called.

Comment: @KevinGalligan I will make a sample repo, that is a good idea. But was hoping to get some answers at the GitHub / discussion portal.

Comment: You should post the samples there as well. In general, when submitting a bug, a sample project makes getting help much more likely. Everybody working on open-source projects does so around their other main work, so there's limited time to focus on anything submitted. With this kind of thing especially. The time difference is dramatic enough that I would assume there's some kind of config issue. If not, room is calling some kind of optimized function that sqldelight is not.

Comment: @KevinGalligan the issue is gone after building the release variant of the app. I have commented on the issue on GH and closed it. Thank you for your support and feedback, have a great Christmas :)